# Git diff get all content

Tags: git, git-bash

I use git diff-tree commit and I have only changes in commit but I want all content of files with this commit.

for example I have  in content in file:

```
function add (item) {
  list.add(item)
}
function pop() {
  list.pop()
}
```

and I made change:

```
 function add (item) {
      list.add(item.name)
 }
```

After run git diff-tree commit I have only:

```
 function add (item) {
      list.add(item)  // it is checked as like removed 
 }
 function add (item) {
          list.add(item.name) // it is checked like as added 
 }
```

I woulde like

```
function add (item) {
      list.add(item)  // it is checked like as removed 
}
function add (item) {
      list.add(item.name) // it is checked like as added 
}
function pop() {
  list.pop()
}
```

I woulde like to return me all content where changes was made not only change

Answer (score 0):

In your 3 functions, there are 2 **similar** signatures,

```
function add (item) {

}
```

I think that's the reason this couldn't work as you expected

Comment: I have two function, but when I run "git diff-tree commit" I have only output when function when I change not all content